# Converting JS to CoffeScript, missing operand?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, highcharts, coffeescript, erb

I've got a HighCharts javascript that i'm trying to convert to CoffeeScript, using some online converters.

However all of them error out with "missing operand"

Here's the code

```
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
      series: [{
        name: "<%= x %>'",
        data: [
        <% @sprice = @price * @quantity %>
        <% 0.upto(@years).each do |stack| %>
          <%= number_with_precision(@sprice, precision: 2) %>,
        <% @sprice = ((@sprice*percentage)/100)+@sprice %>,
        <% end %>]
      }]
  });
});
```

Where's the missing operand tho? Does it have something to do with embedded ruby inside my JS script?

Script is working as intended inside HTML view file. But i'm trying to move it into controller's js file to clean it up abit. Controller's js file is in coffescript by default, so that's where im kind of stuck.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I don't think any converting tool could take care of erb. Better to do that with plain Javascript.

Comment: Yeah figured that :D I guess ill just use js.erb. Now need to pass rails object captured to javascript somehow... Google time!

Comment: Why do all that work in ERB at all? If `@years` is small then ERB a couple simple scalars and then build the array in CoffeeScript; if `@years` is large then do the heavy lifting in your controller and stuff the data into your CoffeeScript as a one line JSON blob. Or AJAX it or split the data out into a separate piece of JavaScript and leave the code as CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above:

> If @years is small
>
> > then ERB a couple simple scalars and then build the array in CoffeeScript;
>
> If @years is large
>
> > then do the heavy lifting in your controller and stuff the data into your CoffeeScript as a one line JSON blob.
>
> Or AJAX it or split the data out into a separate piece of JavaScript and leave the code as CoffeeScript.

**References**

- [CoffeeScript, TypeScript? How about JavaScript](http://www.innoarchitech.com/coffeescript-typescript-javascript/)